# Rails nested resource - route not being created

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did a nested resource in rails:

```
resources :courses do
  resource :members
end
```

and get the following routes:

```
course_members      POST     /courses/:course_id/members(.:format)            {:controller=>"members", :action=>"create"}
new_course_members  GET      /courses/:course_id/members/new(.:format)        {:controller=>"members", :action=>"new"} 
edit_course_members GET      /courses/:course_id/members/edit(.:format)       {:controller=>"members", :action=>"edit"}
                    GET      /courses/:course_id/members(.:format)            {:controller=>"members", :action=>"show"}
                    PUT      /courses/:course_id/members(.:format)            {:controller=>"members", :action=>"update"}
                    DELETE   /courses/:course_id/members(.:format)            {:controller=>"members", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Why has no route for action=>show been created?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything else in your route file that might be conflicting? Also, how are you viewing the routes? When I add what you have above to my route file I get the following:

```
course_members     GET    /courses/:course_id/members(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"members"}
                   POST   /courses/:course_id/members(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"members"}
new_course_member  GET    /courses/:course_id/members/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"members"}
edit_course_member GET    /courses/:course_id/members/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"members"}
course_member      GET    /courses/:course_id/members/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"members"}
                   PUT    /courses/:course_id/members/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"members"}
                   DELETE /courses/:course_id/members/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"members"}
courses            GET    /courses(.:format)                             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"courses"}
                   POST   /courses(.:format)                             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"courses"}
new_course         GET    /courses/new(.:format)                         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"courses"}
edit_course        GET    /courses/:id/edit(.:format)                    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"courses"}
course             GET    /courses/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"courses"}
                   PUT    /courses/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"courses"}
                   DELETE /courses/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"courses"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The route was indeed created. I think you are mistaking the helpers for the actual route.

```
GET      /courses/:course_id/members(.:format) {:controller=>"members", :action=>"show"}
```

I think your confusion comes from the fact that you have three helpers (course_members, new_course_members & edit_course_members), and you don't have a "show_course_members".

Rails creates only one helper for the actions SHOW, UPDATE, DESTROY and CREATE because you can tell one from another by the HTTP method invoked.

#### ACTION   |  HTTP METHOD

SHOW     -     GET

UPDATE    -    PUT

CREATE    - POST

DESTROY   - DELETE

If you call course_members_path with a GET method, Rails will invoke the show action.

One other thing that I noticed, however: you create the resource for only one member (hence resource in singuler at routes.rb). One course really has only one member?
The word **resource** (singular) at the routes.rb should be used if you have a **has_one** relation on the controller.
If you have a **has_many**, you should use **resources** (plural) instead.

Take a look at
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

Best regards